# What's the order of the Final Fantasy games?

Tags: final-fantasy-series

There are a lot of Final Fantasy video games out there, and I don't know which one to play.  What order should they be played in?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Final Fantasy is like Mario or Zelda; there is no order in which you should play them.

Comment: Presumably, first to last.

Comment: First way: start from the first one, and work your way up to the latest (Keep in mind a couple of them are MMOs), this order may help build an appreciation for how each iteration builds on and (tries to) improve on the mechanics and story of its predecessors. Second way: find one you really like to start with to get you hooked, and then branch out into the rest of the series, as they are all largely unrelated, the order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It doesn't really matter.**

Despite their numbered iterations, most of the Final Fantasy games are in no way related to each other. There's no overarching plot between the various entries, no shared setting, nothing that implies any particular order that they should be played in, plot-wise. A few exceptions do exist, however.

- FFIV: The After Years - Sequel to FFIV
- X-2 - Direct sequel to X
- Final Fantasy XII: Revenant Wings - Sequel to XII
- XIII-2 - Direct sequel to XIII
- Lightning Returns: Final Fantasy XIII - Sequel to XIII-2
- Final Fantasy Tactics A2 - Sequel to Final Fantasy Tactics Advance
- Dirge of Cerberus - Sequel to VII
- Before Crisis - Prequel to VII
- Crisis Core - Prequel to VII

Comment: Don't forget about Lightning's Return: XIII

Comment: @Wondercricket Whoops, had that, but forgot to put it back in when I reformatted. Thanks.

Comment: There's a *bit* of a shared setting in [Ivalice](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Ivalice_Alliance). But, yeah, the main Roman numeral games are largely unconnected save for a few recurring names (Cid) and creatures (Moogles, Chocobos, etc)